# Переменная в атрибуте html-тега

Tags: javascript, html

В некоторый html-тег нужно в data-параметр вставить значение переменной, которая определяется и инициализируется ниже. Я делаю так:

```
<div data-parameter="somevar">...</div>
<script>
    var somevar = [{...},{...},{...}];
</script>
```

Можно ли так делать? У меня не работает почему-то

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать? У вас в коде атрибут `data-parameter` является просто строкой, а дальше в коде `js` вы просто объявляете переменную и присваиваете ей некоторый массив объектов.

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос, чтоб он был понятен всем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вы сделали - нельзя. Нужно приблизительно так:

```
<div id="my_id" data-parameter="somevar">...</div>
<script>
    var value = 'значение, которое хотим присвоить атрибуту';
    $('div#my_id').attr('data-parameter', value);
</script>
```

(использую jQuery, т.к. не знаю, как изменить атрибут тега на чистом js)

Comment: Спасибо, так заработало